# Cake PHP Cache helper, cacheAction

Tags: cakephp, caching

I have the following in my controller:

```
var $cacheAction = array(
            'view/' => 432000,
            'pricelist/'=>'100000',
            'latest/' => '100000');
```

That is to cache the views for 5 days. I also enabled cache in core.php and included the cache helper in my controller.

The cache files are created correctly in tmp/cache/views/ but they don't seem to last for 5 days. If I do a file listing all files have been created in the last 3-4 minutes.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need another syntax for cache action?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your actions using Models which change requently? From the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/348/Clearing-the-Cache)

> It is important to remember that the Cake will clear a cached view if a model used in the cached view is modified. For example, if a cached view uses data from the Post model, and there has been an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query made to a Post, the cache for that view is cleared, and new content is generated on the next request.

Comment: No the model of this page isn't updated. BUT!
The page shows pictures which a logged on user can add to his/her basket. BasketImages which is another model does get updated.
Besides this view contains a div which reads SESSION variables and states how many images the user has in his basket.
Can this be the reason?

Comment: So I have tested that whenever you add an image to your basket, cache get cleared.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: You might be able to do something where you use ajax on the portion that is dynamic, so that basket is coming from a view different from the one you are trying cache.

Answer (score 0):

My models are:

events **hasMany** Images

Basket **belongsTo** events
       **hasMany** BasketImages

BasketImages **belongsTo** images
             **belongsTo** basket

So I have cached the page events/view/id. In this view I have:

```
<?php if (($c=count($basketImages))>0) echo $c; ?>
```

and then there are some photos and a button which makes an *ajax* call like: /baskets/add/imageID

In basket/add, if user doesn't have a basket it creates one, and it also creates a BasketImage record with the current imageID.

So my question is do my page fall in the category where:

> It is important to remember that the Cake will clear a cached view if a model used in the cached view is modified. (cookbook)

Does adding a basket and basketImage make events/view cache expiry? Can I use:

```
<cake:nocache> <?php if (($c=count($basketImages))>0) echo $c;?><cake:nocache>
```

Comment: This should have been added to your question instead of posted as an answer.